# posting to server with fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch, progressive-web-apps

im trying to change the favorite state of a post to either `true` or `false` on my server but i keep having this same issue over and over. i click on the favorite button and sure enough the favorite state changes. but then when i click on it again nothing happens.nothing changes. then if i delete the static cache and click on the favorite button it does change the favorite state but only the first time. basically every time i need to change the state i have to delete the cache.same thing is happening when i try to add reviews to the server. this is my code for adding favorites to the server

```
static setFavorite() {
      const id = self.restaurant.id;
      const fav_state = self.restaurant.is_favorite;
      const fav_div = document.getElementById('fav_div');
      let image = document.getElementById('fav_img');
      console.log("fav", fav_state);

      if (fav_state == 'true') {
    DBHelper.toggleFavorite(id, false);
    } else {
      DBHelper.toggleFavorite(id, true);
    }
  }

  static toggleFavorite(id, value) {
    fetch('http://localhost:1337/restaurants/' + id + '/?is_favorite=' + value,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },
        value: JSON.stringify(value)
      })
    .then(r => r.json())
      .then(res => console.log(value));
  }
```

Comment: Can you also add to your post what is the content of value in `setFavorite` as well as right in the beginning of `toggleFavorite` and on the end of it as well? Also are we certain the address is not `'http://localhost:1337/restaurants/' + id + '?is_favorite=' + value`? (no / before the ?)

Comment: yes the url is correct. this is the url used for the api `http://localhost:1337/restaurants/<restaurant_id>/?is_favorite=` where is_favorite could be either true or false

Answer (score 0):

Feels like some code is missing here. It looks like setFavorite() function takes `fat_state` from `self.restaurant.is_favorite` and passes that value to the `toggleFavorite`. But there is nothing in the code you provided which shows how `self.restaurant.is_favorite` is modified.

I'm not sure if in your code you're forgetting to flip it to from `true` to `false` and from `false` to `true`.

Also on a side note (for better javascript in your code)
Do not use == `true` and maybe try to refactor your code to have a strict comparison (=== true) to avoid any side-effects.
Also not sure why do you need `let image` in your code at all and that image related code you provided.

Comment: that's the thing. on the first hit no matter what the value is the data is modified.but if i try and click it again that's when it stops working.i mean i have the if statement. i don't get why it wouldn't work

Comment: Put console.log() entries there before IF statement (with the value of fav_state) and then inside IF and inside ELSE statements - do you see an output?